# neovim dein "no notification handler registered for ..." plugin

Tags: python-3.x, vim, plugins, neovim

I'm working on a neovim plugin in python3 that is currently loaded locally with dein, it is working correctly but now I am getting this error.

```
 no notification handler registered for ...
```

After getting that error it continues to work. I only get it the first time using the plugin after opening a file.

I tried  :UpdateRemotePlugins
Any idea where I should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I was calling context specific vim functions in the Main **init**